# Removing the lastNode in a singly Linked List

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

Can I check
how do we remove a last node from a single linked list?

is it the same as how we remove the first node?

remove first Node

```
def deleteAtHead(self):
    temp = self.head
    self.head = self.head.next
    delete temp
```

remove last Node

```
def deleteAtTail(self):
    prev = None
    temp = self.tail
    self.tail= self.tail.prev 
    delete temp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to crawl back to the `tail` starting at the head.
The tail is the first node with no next: `next is None`.
Keeping track of the next-to-last (`prev`), you set its `next` to `None`.

```
def deleteAtTail(self):   # remove_last would likely be a better name
    """ removes the last element of the singly linked list
    """
    temp = self.head
    while(temp.next is not None):
        prev  = temp
        temp = temp.next
    prev.next = None
```

Setting `prev.next` to `None` removes the tail node (it will be garbage collected if there are no other references to it)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you not just maintain a pointer to the end of the list? Traversing to the end each time from head is extremely expensive if the list is long and the cost of an extra pointer is extremely low.

Comment: I agree with you, but it is not what the OP asked for - it is also not what a bare bones singly linked list API offers.

Comment: I mean....he uses the variable `self.tail` in his code. I think it was reasonable to assume that OP was maintaining a pointer to the tail of the list, as that would be the intelligent thing to do. I guess I was also wondering who down voted my answer lol. Also did you mean a "bare bones singly linked list ADT?"

Comment: nope, you should not need one (doubly linked lists maintain previous pointers, not singly)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do remove operation in single-linked list with O(n) = c complexity because you don't have reference for previous list node. You will have to traverse to the end of the list remembering current and previous nodes and then you will have to trim previous node from the reference to it's next, which is the last node you are trying to remove. This will always have O(n) = n complexity for single-linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a singly linked list you will have to iterate through the list to get to the node just before tail. I think your function would simply need to be

```
def deleteAtTail(self):
     temp = self.head
     while(temp.next != None):
         if temp.next == tail: #finds the node just before tail
             break
         temp = temp.next
     temp.next = None
     self.tail = temp
```

We set `self.tail = temp` because temp is equal to the node just before the end of the list. So we delete temp (by removing its last reference) and then set tail equal to node we earlier identified as the second to last node in the list as it will in fact be the new end of the list.

**EDIT:**

To address the concerns of some of the comments on this answer. It is good practice to maintain a `head`, `tail` and `current` pointer when dealing with a singly or doubly linked list. Knowing where tail is located is extremely valuable for making insertions into your list something that is computationally reasonable.

This means that your insertion method can go from this:

```
def insert(value):
    temp = self.head
    while(temp.next != None):
        temp = temp.next
    temp.next = Node()
    temp.next.value = value
```

which has a time complexity O(n) to this:

```
def insert(value):
    self.tail.next = Node()
    self.tail.next.value = value
    self.tail = self.tail.next
```

which is has a substantially more favorable time complexity of O(1).

Comment: A node in singly linked list only knows its next, it doesn't know its previous,

Comment: Oh my gosh. I didn't even notice it wasn't doubly linked because OP was using `prev` in his code. I'll edit my response.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque and OP, my example has been updated.

Comment: It is broken,  it doesn't know its tail either... you have to find the tail!

Comment: That is not true. You should update the tail each time you append an element to the list. This allows you to have MUCH faster insertions. I do this all the time in C++.

Comment: Nonsense - all you know is the head and from there, you can find the tail.

Comment: `delete self.tail` is not valid python btw

Comment: why self.tail = temp?

Comment: @Ilja you're right. I've updated the my example to delete the node in a more pythonic manner. OP, I've also added in a line explaining why we are setting `self.tail` to `temp`.

Comment: I can understand this not being the selected answer, but can anyone offer some guidance as to why I received a down vote on my answer? Nothing I've said is wrong, its just not _exactly_ what OP was looking for. Trying to build my rep up and things like this just confuse me.